# Given $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(0)=0$, what can we say about f(x)

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Given $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(0)=0$, what can we deduce about $f(x)$?

I intend to say that $f(x)=x$, but find difficult to prove it. Is my guess correct, or wrong?

Comment: This is the Cauchy equation. It has linear solutions (and nontrivial solutions assuming axiom of choice).

Comment: We could say the domain of our question - talking about reals, integers, rational numbers? $f(x)=2x$ is an answer. $f(x)=3x$ is an answer.

Comment: On the reals, there are a whole class of answers that are really ugly, unless you require $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: The condition $f(0)=0$ is redundant, since it is obtained from the other condition for $x=y=0$: $f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0) \implies f(0)=2f(0) \implies f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=-x$.  THen

$$0=f(0)=f(x+-x)=f(x)+f(-x)$$

Then

$$f(x)=-f(-x)$$
or
$$-f(x)=f(-x)$$

What do you know about equations that have this form?